# Comment and uncomment by the same key strokes

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

At the moment, my commenting and un-commenting is done by two different strokes listed below:

```
nnoremap <leader>c 0<insert>//<Esc>
nnoremap <leader><leader>c :s;^\s*//<cr>
```

Which is tedious for me, can someone help me to write a mapping macro that  `<leader>c` stroke removes the comments, if there are any, or add one otherwise.

If the comments/uncomments will all be done by the single lovely `<leader>c`, that would be a lot less pain in my ......

Thanks!

**p.s.**

If you intended to learn Vimrc, read the answer, try those cool solutions. However, here comes the better pain killer: [NERD Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of effect simply with an expression map and the ternary operator:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>c getline('.')[0:1] == '//'
  \ ? ":s;^\s*//<cr>"
  \ : "0<insert>//<Esc>"
```

An expression mapping maps your `<leader>c` to the result of an expression. In this case, it tests if the first two character in the line are `//` and then carries one of the commands you already wrote.

For more details, see:

- [`:help :map-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-expression)
- [`:help expr1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr1)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use your own mappings you can try something like this:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>c IsCommented() ? ":s;^\s*//<cr>" : "0<insert>//<Esc>"

function! IsCommented()
    return substitute(getline('.'), '^\s*', '', '')[0] == "/" && substitute(getline('.'), '^\s*', '', '')[0] == substitute(getline('.'), '^\s*', '', '')[1]
endfunction
```

`IsCommented()` will return true is the first two characters of the current line are `/` and false otherwise (note that it will ignore the leading whitespaces) and the mapping is conditioned by the result of this command (See [`:h :map-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-expression))

However, I would recommend not to reinvent the wheel and use a plugin like [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) or [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) which are pretty powerful and lightweight.

**Edit** As [@Rich said](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14867/comment-and-uncomment-by-the-same-key-strokes/14870#comment25467_14870): [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) never gets any love.

Comment: Man, [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) never gets any love.

Comment: Ahah @Rich actually I used NERDCommenter when I started using plugins and never switched, I added commentary to give OP some choice but I never really looked for another commenting plugin.

Comment: I actually haven't gotten around to trying tcomment yet, either ;). Neither NERDCommenter nor vim-commentary can be configured to comment the way I like, though, so I actually still comment/uncomment manually using visual-block mode!

Comment: Whatever floats your boat as they say :) I actually like a lot the "sexy commenting" (`<leader>cs`) and the "comment and yank" (`<leader>cy`) features of NERDCommenter.

Comment: @statox You know what!, NERDCommenter is very sexy!

Comment: @SLN It is one of the few plugin I kept even though I try to get rid of as many plugins as I can :)

Comment: @statox totally agree.